# Do I need a SIP Server / Registrar to implement a SIP intercom system?

Tags: android, ios, sip, voip, sdp

Do I need a PBX or SIP server to allow two devices to communicate via SIP?

Lets assume one device (Android or IOS) knows the IP address of another.  Couldn't that device send the INVITE directly to the other and get a conversation started, without the need for a SIP server?  Or am I oversimplifying and the SIP server does something magical that I'm missing?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is [peer-to-peer SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer_SIP) which does not require any servers in the middle. So yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

As per SIP standard there is no restriction of SIP server to be use.

Server is use because we do not have to remember location (IP Port) of all SIP users.
When user register with server, Server take care of location of user.
(Server provide so many other features but to make this description easy ignoring all)

But in your case as you know IP address of another user no need of server.

Just make sure a SIP stack you are using is allow you to send INVITE without REGISTER. Because some stack restrict client to send INVITE without successfully register.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's what I was hoping.